# Command Variable Outputs

Tags: html, batch-file, variables, output

Basically, I was working on some code, dealing with creating a text file, then later reading the text file line by line, and turning each line into a variable, which is then echoed within other text to make the variable fit into html code, which will later be used in a website. Here is my code:

```
    @echo off
    set file=file
    cd %cd%
    for /d %%b in (*) do dir /ad /on /s /b "%%b" >> get_dirs.txt
    for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (get_dirs.txt) do ( 
    echo %%A > tmpfile.txt
    set /p t= < tmpfile.txt
    pause
    echo ^<a href="%file%:///%t%"^>%t%^</a^>
    )
    pause
```

Ignore the pauses they were being used for previous debugging. My main problem is that my command prompt is giving me an output of `<a href="file:///"></a>`
which is want I want accept my variable `%t%` is not being echoed with the rest of html code. I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Standard `delayed expansion` problem. Search SO for hundreds of articles about `setlocal delayedexpansion`

Your code is written better

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (get_dirs.txt) do ( 
 echo ^<a href="%file%:///%%A"^>%%A^</a^>
)
```

If, for reasons you don't reveal, you actually want the variable in `t` then

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (get_dirs.txt) do ( 
 set "t=%%A"
 echo ^<a href="%file%:///%%A"^>%%A^</a^>
)
```

will do that, but you'd syill need to either use `delayedexpansion` or a subroutine to use the dynamic value assigned to `t`.

Comment: So, because `%%A` is for what folder is currently beeing traversed, I can just use that? And just to clarify, either way with or without the `t`, I still need to use `delayedexpansion`, right?

Comment: Since `%%A` contains your required string, you can use it while it is in scope (within the `for` loop) as though it was an ordinary environment variable - with the exception that you can't use substringing on it. If you need to substring or manipute the value, then it needs to be transfered to a standard variable and then the manipulation must be conducted either by using `delayedexpansion` methods on the standard variable or in a subroutine.

Comment: So, I'm not sure if this is because of the delayedexpansion, everytime I run the file it adds on, which makes sense because you have to append it when using the loop, but it still adds on even if I clear or delete the file at the beginning of the code. Not sure how to combat this.

Comment: You haven't shown how you're deleting the file. `>>` will append to any existing file. You don't use the variable `file` and `cd %cd%` is superfluous. I'd remove the `for /d` part since the `/s` switch on the `dir` will scan all subdirectories, so your code reads "for each directory, do a directory-and-subdirectories list" Perhaps knowing `(sequence of commands)>filename` will create `filename` anew containing the output from `(...)` would be helpful. Note that this is parenthesising, possibly apparently needlessly, a statement[-sequence]